# Absorption of Topical Magnesium

Tags: human-biology

Can Magnesium be absorbed through the skin? Some athletes believe that Homeopathic magnesium lotions can reduce muscle pain. I've tried this and it doesn't work nor can I see how it can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Homeopathic magnesium lotions don't* contain magnesium, so it seems a little irrelevant whether or not magnesium can be absorbed through the skin. However, magnesium ions can [definitely be absorbed through the skin](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15080493). There's no reason why that should reduce muscle pain(especially because ions would disperse throughout the bloodstream etc etc), but magnesium can be absorbed through the skin fairly efficiently.

*Footnote: they do, but not on purpose. If correctly prepared they would contain zero atoms of magnesium(depending on what 'strength' they are), but that kind of purity is impossible.